# How to debug the next JavaScript event in Chrome, with scripts running in background?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

In Chrome DevTools, I want to be able to hit F8 (pause script execution), and then interact with the page's elements to see what script it fires. The goal is to pause script execution as soon as I click on a button, for example.

However, when hitting F8, I'm brought to a certain script file in the Sources tab. It seems to be constantly running, perhaps on a timer. I hit Shift+F11 to step out of the function, but this brings me to the "unpuased" state again in Chrome.

In this case, the script running in the background is [Plupload](http://plupload.com/) jQuery plugin.

Can I deactive or ignore those scripts running constantly in the backgound, in order to be able to debug page interaction events?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the DOM, XHR, and Event Listener [breakpoints menus](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts-breakpoints#xhr) on the Sources tab to target the operations you would like to investigate. This approach will probably take some experimentation and practice, but it may give you the control you seek.

Comment: I had overlooked the XHR breakpoints (as I didn't know what that meant). But that could be another tool to fix such debugging. Thanks.

Comment: To add to this comment, the "Event Listener Breakpoints" allow you to set Mouse events, such as Click. I don't know if this is a new feature.